# Cannot extract a substring properly with strtok in c

Tags: c

I have a list words that I want to separate in different `char *`. Then I use this `char *` in my `send_file` function, but it doesn't work. I have some binary printed. But it works fine when I hard code it.

input from my client console:
client> + tosend8.c

output client:
STRING : +
STRING SWITCH : tosend8.c
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

output server console:
ڀdP7@5;#|}P@I@  etc.

I think my client cannot find the file stored in the repertory when I split the input buffer. But when I hardcode it its work perfectly

Main:

```
//CMD : client adr port delay
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SERVER = argv[1];
    PORT = atoi(argv[2]);
    DELAY = atoi(argv[3]);
    
    printf("SERVER : %s  -  PORT : %d  -  DELAY : %d  \n", SERVER, PORT, DELAY);
    
    int socketfd = connect_to(SERVER, PORT);
    
    //PROMPT
    puts("Client Version 0.0.0.0.1");
    puts("Press Ctrl+c to Exit\n");
    
    //char** path = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    
    int i = 0;
    
    while (1) {
        fputs("client> ", stdout);
        fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
    
        const char *separators = " ";
    
        char *strToken = strtok(input, separators);
        while (strToken != NULL) {
            path[i] = strToken;
            i++;
            //printf("%s\n", strToken);
            // On demande le token suivant.
            strToken = strtok(NULL, separators);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            printf("STRING : %s\n", path[i]);
        }
    
        switch (input[0])
        {
        case '+':
            printf("STRING SWITCH : %s\n", path[1]); //BUG
            send_message(-1, strlen("tosend.c"), "tosend.c", -1, socketfd);
            //send_file("tosend8.c", socketfd); //==> works perfectly
            send_file(path[1], socketfd); //BUG
            break;
```

send file:

```
//send program to server (ok)
void send_file(char *filename, int socketfd) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    char data[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
    while (fgets(data, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        swrite(socketfd, &data, BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
    printf("[+]File data sent successfully.\n");
    sclose(socketfd);
}
```

Comment: Hi! The code is hardly understandable for me, because I have no idea what is the definition and declaration of *input* as well as allocating *path* seems to be commented but you treat it like it wasn't.

Comment: You are reading *variable length lines*, but sending *fixed length buffers*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [example] as well as example input and output.

Comment: regarding: `SERVER = argv[1];
    PORT = atoi(argv[2]);
    DELAY = atoi(argv[3]);`  do not access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the user actually included the expected command line parameters

Comment: what is the function: `connect_to()`?  where is the definition of `input[]`?

Comment: what is `swrite()`? what is `send_message()`?

Comment: regarding: `while (fgets(data, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        swrite(socketfd, &data, BUFFER_SIZE);` just because the code ask for (a maximum) input of `BUFFER_SIZE` does not mean that many characters were input.  Suggest: `swrite( socketfd, data, strlen(data ) );`   Note: remember that a bare array reference degrades to the address of the first byte of the array

Comment: where is `data[]` declared?   this statement: `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {` masks the `path[i] = strToken; i++;` used in the index to set the pointers in `data[]`.   It also only displays the first two strings pointed to by `data[]`.   Can there be more that three(3) sub strings pointed to?  Please post some typical input lines

Comment: sorry, why your code has no `#include` directives? Please, read [How to create a Minima, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and modify your posted program with something that you have already run locally and can be run without modifications to be able to do a correct diagnostic.